# Mocking inbound Jax-RS Response with Entity

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0, moxy

I am trying to unit test a class that uses Jersey 2 Client + Moxy to call a REST service. I want to mock the response, which contains a large JSON object. The code is structured in such a way that I can override/mock the following method:

```
protected Response doPost(String path, Entity<?> entity) {
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = getRestInvocationBuilder(path);
    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(entity);
    return response;
}
```

I would like to somehow inject some example JSON data (ideally from a file) into the Response at this point, prior to `readEntity()` being called, so that I can test that the JSON data is correctly unmarshalled into the target object.

Is there any way to do this? Note that this is for unit testing and therefore I'm not interested in running a local server or other integration testing techniques.

I'm aware similar questions have been asked, but many seem out of date or have incomplete solutions. The closest solution suggested is to mock the `readEntity()` method of the Response, this will not work for me because it would involve creating an object of the desired type to return, rather than creating one from the example JSON data.